# Issues in inserting comma separated strings to table

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have following 3 parameters from stored procedure

```
P_Param1 = 12

P_Paramj2= 'val:15,val:16'

P_param3 = 'Name:check values,Name:bv,Name:cv'
```

I have a table and need to insert above details and final table looks like below

```
proID  CatID CatName
12     15   check values
12     15   bv
12     15   cv
12     16   check values
12     16   bv
12     16   cv
```

I have written a query to split `P_param3` as below and getting splitted values but stuck in generating loops to make a table like above.

```
SELECT
    regexp_substr('Name:check values,Name:bv,Name:cv', '(Name:)?(.*?)(,Name:|$)', 1, level, NULL,
                  2) AS "CatName"
FROM
    dual
CONNECT BY
    level <= regexp_count('Name:check values,Name:bv,Name:cv', 'Name:');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split the `catId`s into rows and split the `catName`s into rows and then `CROSS JOIN` them and insert.

You can do it with simple (fast) string functions using:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE insertCats(
  p_proid    IN table_name.proid%TYPE,
  p_catids   IN VARCHAR2,
  p_catnames IN VARCHAR2
)
IS
  c_catid_prefix   CONSTANT VARCHAR2(10) := 'val:';
  c_catid_length   CONSTANT PLS_INTEGER  := LENGTH(c_catid_prefix);
  c_catname_prefix CONSTANT VARCHAR2(10) := 'Name:';
  c_catname_length CONSTANT PLS_INTEGER  := LENGTH(c_catname_prefix);
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO table_name (proid, catid, catname)
  WITH catid_bounds (catids, spos, epos) AS (
    SELECT p_catids,
           1 + c_catid_length,
           INSTR(p_catids, ',', 1 + c_catid_length)
    FROM   DUAL
  UNION ALL
    SELECT catids,
           epos + 1 + c_catid_length,
           INSTR(catids, ',', epos + 1 + c_catid_length)
    FROM   catid_bounds
    WHERE  epos > 0
  ),
  catids (catid) AS (
    SELECT CASE epos
           WHEN 0
           THEN SUBSTR(catids, spos)
           ELSE SUBSTR(catids, spos, epos - spos)
           END
    FROM   catid_bounds
  ),
  catname_bounds (catnames, spos, epos) AS (
    SELECT p_catnames,
           1 + c_catname_length,
           INSTR(p_catnames, ',', 1 + c_catname_length)
    FROM   DUAL
  UNION ALL
    SELECT catnames,
           epos + 1 + c_catname_length,
           INSTR(catnames, ',', epos + 1 + c_catname_length)
    FROM   catname_bounds
    WHERE  epos > 0
  ),
  catnames (catname) AS (
    SELECT CASE epos
           WHEN 0
           THEN SUBSTR(catnames, spos)
           ELSE SUBSTR(catnames, spos, epos - spos)
           END
    FROM   catname_bounds
  )
  SELECT p_proid,
         i.catid,
         n.catname
  FROM   catids i CROSS JOIN catnames n;
END;
/
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=066602548b5a2ff730c41955255e998e)*

Comment: How can we add additional columns here. In case third colum contains additional comma inside string, will it be an issue ?

Comment: @atc You can add more columns, just split the third string and `CROSS JOIN` again. If you have a supplementary question then [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: I tried but not working, Can you give an example to add additional column

Comment: @atc Copy the `p_catnames` parameter in the signature and paste it to create a fourth parameter and change it to another name. Copy the `c_catname_prefix` and `c_catname_length` constant declarations and paste it to create constants for your new input. Copy `catname_bounds` and `catnames` sub-query factoring clauses and paste and change `catname` to something appropriate for the new column. Add a `CROSS JOIN`. You just need to do exactly what was done before and change the names.

Comment: I tried but not working. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=0cf382f8b1659209d8c604e14831f19c

Comment: @atc You have copy-pasted the subquery factoring clauses but you have not changed the identifiers so there are duplicates. If you just want to add the parameter and do not need to split it then [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=61f4c5d6c49ee30c0ad35840bd4ab185).